# how to configure OOTB "inStockFlag" and "reviewAvgRating" index property as facets

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Please help to achieve this. I added these two properties from non facets index property to facet index property in `solr.implex` file. Run the full indexer , 
 added customer review for some of the products and approved the status as well in spite of that these two properties are not showing as facets in storefront.

Please guide me step by step how can I achieve this. I have already wasted 2.5 days to achieve the same.

I am using `hybris 6.4`

Answer (score 0):

First, run the below Impex form the HAC. Don't forget to change **apparel-ukProductType** with your Indexed type.

```
$solrIndexedType=apparel-ukProductType

# Facet properties       
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty ; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true] ; name[unique=true]      ; type(code) ; sortableType(code) ; currency[default=false] ; localized[default=false] ; multiValue[default=false] ; useForSpellchecking[default=false] ; useForAutocomplete[default=false] ; fieldValueProvider                      ; valueProviderParameters[map-delimiter=|] ; ftsPhraseQuery[default=false] ; ftsPhraseQueryBoost ; ftsQuery[default=false] ; ftsQueryBoost ; ftsFuzzyQuery[default=false] ; ftsFuzzyQueryBoost ; ftsWildcardQuery[default=false] ; ftsWildcardQueryType(code)[default=POSTFIX] ; ftsWildcardQueryBoost ; ftsWildcardQueryMinTermLength ; facetType(code) ; facetSort(code) ; priority ; visible ; facet[default=true]
                                  ; $solrIndexedType                         ; reviewAvgRating        ; double     ;                    ;                         ; TRUE                     ;                           ;                                    ;                                   ; productReviewAverageRatingValueProvider ;                                          ;                               ;                     ;                         ;               ;                              ;                    ;                                 ;                                             ;                       ;                               ; MultiSelectOr   ; Custom          ; 10000    ; true    ;
                                  ; $solrIndexedType                         ; inStockFlag            ; boolean    ;                    ;                         ;                          ;                           ;                                    ;                                   ; productInStockFlagValueProvider         ;                                          ;                               ;                     ;                         ;               ;                              ;                    ;                                 ;                                             ;                       ;                               ; MultiSelectOr   ; Custom          ; 10000    ; true    ;
```

You can do the same changes from backoffice/hmc.

Go to System > Facet Search > Indexed Type > select your type from list > Find the inStockFlag under Properties filed > scroll to end (right) to edit inStockFlag properties > In popup go to facet setting tab > Mark Facet to true and edit other fields.

Lastly, run the full indexer.

Comment: Hi Ankit,
thanks for the reply. I am trying the same but still these two facets are not comming.

Comment: In that case, you have to debug the code and also cross check your facets in the Solr

Comment: Go to http://localhost:8983/solr/, select your core and check the data in your index. If the data is empty, solr might hide it.

Comment: Hi All, I have checked all the above step but still I am not able to see these two facets on storefront.  Do we need to change some configure parameter? After debuging I am getting below exception:  "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
 at de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.search.converters.populator.SearchResultProductPopulator.populate(SearchResultProductPopulator.java:166)

Comment: Debug that class further and see which facet causing the issue. Check at SearchResultProductPopulator.java:166.

Comment: contact me over the email I will help you out!